# vue.js Unit Test - Error in mounted hook

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js

I'm using Jasmine as unit test framework, and I would like to know how could I know if a vue is correctly mounted. Is there a function, an API from VueJS, a receipt to know the state of the view ?

Actually..the unit test is passing but at the console (terminal or under the browser) I got the the following error : **ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: (found in xxxx ) -  ReferenceError: $ is not defined'**

Then I would like that my unit test has a failure on this kind of error instead of passing......?

Here is a quick snapshot of the code:

```
describe("location component tests suite", () => {

    const getComponent = (data) => {
        let vm = new Vue({
            template : "<div>"
                + "<location"
                + " :data='data'"
                + " label='pick'"
                + " placeholder='placeholder'"
                + " required>"
                + "</location></div>",

            data: {
                data
            }
        });

        return vm;
    };

    it("Validate mount", () => {
        const data= { 'data' : { 'value' : 'VUE'} };
        const vm = getComponent(data).$mount();
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('div.location-wrapper').getAttribute('class')).toBe('location-wrapper');
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('input').getAttribute('name')).toBe('pick');
    });
});
```

Thank you !

Comment: The `<location>` component's code is probably more relevant here.

Comment: I do not want to know from where the error comes... I just want to know if there is a way to know if error occurs during .$mount() because the unit test is not failing.

Comment: The location component is a complex component, not really relevant here... and the cause of the failing is related to $ (JQuery) as it is not part of the build of the component. Making an import solved the problem....

What I'm looking for, is a way to trap such kind of error...during the .$mount() to make my test failing instead of to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`Vue.config.errorHandler`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler) API which is introduced since `v2.2.0`.

1. You can declare a variable as an error-thrown flag (i.e. `errorThrown`).

   ```
    let errorThrown = false;
   ```
2. Define the errorHandler function so that `errorThrown` will be switched to `true` when it's triggered.

   ```
    Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
      console.log(info);
      if(info.includes('mounted')) {
        errorThrown = true;
      }
    };
   ```
3. Check `errorThrown` by using `expect` API in jasmine.

   ```
    expect(errorThrown).toBe(false);  // Test will fail here
   ```

Check the working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/zyso8awt/).
In this way, errors occurred in mounted method will be catched and force unit test to fail.